# Kendo MVC cascading features works for one but not for the other. Javascript not firing

Tags: kendo-ui, asp.net-mvc-5, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-combobox

I am implementing kendo combo box cascading feature in my MVC application. I have one parent combo box called Sales Organisation and two child combo boxes called Sales Office and Service Account manager respectively. The cascading features works only for the Service Account manager combo box. Not sure what the problem is. I am trying to filter the Sales Office with Country Code field that is passed from the parent combo box control Sales Organisation. Both the child controls respective controller methods are getting called but on the second child controllers javascript function GetFilterOption1()  gets triggered. I dont know for what reason first function GetFilterOption() doesnt get triggered. I have checked the developer tools and dont see any errors. If I do an alert of  $('#CountryCode').val(), I get value. The function itself is not firing

**Sales Organisation (Parent Combo box)**

```
<div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Company, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(model => model.CountryCode)

        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%" })
        .DataTextField("CompanyCodeCompany")
        .DataValueField("CountryCode")
        .Filter("contains")
        .MinLength(3)
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Read(read => read.Action("RequestHeader_SalesOrganisation", "Request").Type(HttpVerbs.Post))
        .ServerFiltering(true)
        )

                        )
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Company, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
```

**Sales Office (First Child combo box)**

```
  <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SalesOffice, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(model => model.SalesOfficeID)

         .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%" })
        .DataTextField("SalesOffice")
        .DataValueField("SalesOfficeID")
        .AutoBind(false)
        .Value("")
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Read(read =>
            {
                read.Action("RequestHeader_SalesOffice", "Request")
                    .Type(HttpVerbs.Post)
                    .Data("GetFilterOption");
            }).ServerFiltering(true)
            ).CascadeFrom("CountryCode").Filter("contains")

                        )
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SalesOffice, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
```

**Service Account Manager (Second Child combo)**

```
 <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NameOfResponsiblePerson, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-5" })
            <div class="col-md-7 col-md-pull-1">
                @(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(model => model.PersonResponsibleMasterDataId)
         // .Name("Sam")
         .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%" })
        .DataTextField("NameOfResponsiblePerson")
        .DataValueField("PersonResponsibleMasterDataId")

        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Read(read =>
        {
            read.Action("RequestHeader_PersonResponsibleMasterData", "Request")
                .Type(HttpVerbs.Post)
                .Data("GetFilterOption1");
        }).ServerFiltering(true)
        ).CascadeFrom("CountryCode").Filter("contains")


                )
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function GetFilterOption() {
       return { id: $('#CountryCode').val() }
}

function GetFilterOption1() {
    return { id: $('[name = "CountryCode"]').data("kendoComboBox").text().split('-')[0] }
}
```

Comment: Double-check everything...I just pasted your code into a test project view, implemented mock Read actions for each ComboBox, and I get both javascript functions firing when I make a selection in the first ComboBox.  I have not modified your code in any way.

Comment: Just changing the name of the filter worked for me. Quite strange